# How to find out sd card partition in dev/block?

Tags: sd-card, permissions, partitions, terminal, ext4

In order to mount an ext4-formated sd card in Android I followed [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2424900) guide.

In the bash script *msd2.sh* is followking command:

`mount -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /storage/extSdCard && sleep 5 && /system/bin/vold`

So in this part the `mmcblk1p1`-partition shall be mounted in `/storage/extSdCard`.

1. How can I find out which of the partitions in `dev/block` is my sd-card ?

Furthermore I cannot `mkdir` a folder in `/storage` to have an equivalent mountpoint: `mkdir failed for /storage/extSdCard, Read-only file system`

2. How do I get read-write access of `\storage` ?

Info:

- Phone: Sony Xperia Z1
- Model number: C6903
- Android version: 5.1.1
- Build Number: 14.6.A.1.236

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How can I find out which of the partitions in dev/block is my sd-card ?

By default, external memory card's partition is **/dev/block/mmcblk1p1** in all devices.
(Unless if you have partitioned the memory card, then you should know which partition to use, for example, if you have partitioned 32GB memory card as first 16GB as FAT32 partition & second 16GB as EXT4 partition, to use the EXT4 partition, you'll be using *mmcblk1p2*)

> 2. How do I get read-write access of /storage ?

I hope by r/w access you mean creating a directory (mount point) to mount the external SD card.

You cannot do that after the device has booted, atleast since KitKat(?).
The only way to do that would be by editing the **ramdisk** of your **boot.img** according to your requirement.